# save and load scene unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, save

my game doesnt have main menu, just simply levels, when players opens the game i want to continue from last session scene(level) . how do i create binary file(or using playerprefs) . could you please help me how to save scene and load here in my game using binary file. here is my game code. please help me i am stuck here for last few days

```
public class PlatformBuild : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        LoadLevel();
    }
public void LoadLevel() 
    {
    
        float spawnPosZ = -42.86f;

        for (int i = 0; i < PlatformsSize; i++)
        {
            GameObject platform = Instantiate(RandomPlatform, transform);
            platform.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, spawnPosZ);
            platform.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 360));
            spawnedPlatforms.Add(platform);
        }   
        GameObject finalPlatformInstance = Instantiate(finalPlatform, transform);
        finalPlatformInstance.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, spawnPosZ);
    }
}
```

this is my gameManger script,

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
       
 public void NextLevel()
    {        
        LevelCompletedMenu.SetActive(false);            StartCoroutine(LoadFade(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));

    }

    public void RestartLevel()
    {
        score = 0;
        StartCoroutine(LoadReStart());
        GameOver.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(LoadFade(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex));

    }
```

}

Comment: What exactly does `but it didnt work` mean? Get any errors? Are you sure according methods are getting called?

Comment: playerprefs  saving level number but scene not loading

Comment: You should [Debug your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and see what exactly doesn't behave the way you expect it to

Answer (score 0):

Containing a single `int` could be stored fine in a number of ways. You could use a binary file if you don't want people to be able to do some file sleuthing to change which scene they're on, although it would be easier to simply create a text file with a number in it. I'm sure `PlayerPrefs` could also work too. As far as actually doing it, all three are very common tasks so probably with some googling you can find plenty of tutorials about it.

Comment: i dont know how to use binary file ,i have seen tutorials but still couldnt understand properly . could you please help me how to save scene here in my game using binary file . Thank you